# create screen session with custom name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I use screen to manage multiple terminals. They are all named like:

```
5737.ttys000.osxltabc
...
```

Can I create a screen session with a better name than

```
5737.ttys000.osxltabc
```

Is there a command-line argument to configure the name of the screen session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`screen -S <name>` will create it with that name, then `screen -x <name>` will reconnect, or the `-r` approaches.